# convert frame to iframe

Tags: html, asp.net, web

and i got Warnnig "element Frameset is not supported" and "element Frame is not supported". i know i have to change to iframe, but i dont know how.
can you help me? 
thanks

```html
<%@ Page CodeBehind="Payroll.aspx.cs" Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="BM.Payslip.UserServices.EndUser.Payroll"  %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Title/title>
  <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="TEXT/HTML; CHARSET=WINDOWS-1255"/>
  <meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE";/>
  <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE";/>
  <meta http-equiv="EXPIRES" content="now";/>
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store";/>
  <link href="CSS\StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<%--  </link>--%>
  <script  type ="text/javascript" src="ClientSideScripts/JSUtils.js">
  </script>

 </head>
<%--    <body>--%>
    <fraemset border="0"  id="payroll"  onload="javascript:ValidateNoFrames()" rows="85px,*"  frameSpacing="0" frameBorder="0">
        <frameset border="0"      frameSpacing="0" frameBorder="0" cols="*,910px,*">
            <frame src="xmlTry.aspx" id="Frame3" name="kk" noresize="noresize"   >
      <frame src="Main.aspx"  id="HMain">
            <frame src="xmlTry.aspx" id="Frame5" name="kk"  noresize="noresize" >
        </FRAMESET>
 
        <FRAMESET border="0"      frameSpacing="0" frameBorder="0" cols="*,910px,*">
            <frame src="xmlTry.aspx" id="Frame2" name="kk"  noresize="noresize" > 
      <frame src="MainPage.aspx" id="SlipArea" name="SlipArea" noresize="noresize"  > 
            <frame src="xmlTry.aspx" id="Frame1" name="kk"  noresize="noresize"/> 
        </FRAMESET>
 </FRAMESET>
 
<%--    </body>--%>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps like this?

```
<iframe src='xmlTry.aspx' id='xxx' > </iframe >
```

If you are trying to arrange multiple frames in a page you can use multiple iframe and use css property like this :

```
<ol>
<li><iframe src="src1.aspx" style="float:left"></iframe></li>
<li><iframe src="src2.aspx"></iframe></li>
<li><iframe src="src3.aspx" style="float:right"></iframe></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: you can completely remove framesets and work with only iframes, please see my edited answer above